# Реализовывать решение коллизий вместо метода цепочек, открытую адресацию

Tags: c++, хеширование, таблицы

Есть реаализация хэш-таблицы на c++(часть кода с пробеломй):

```
class hashTable
{
private:
    set<string> * table;
    const int alphabet = 29;//размерность алфавита
    const int size = 2603921;

public:
    hashTable()
    {
        table = new set<string>[size];
    }

int getHash(string str)
{
    unsigned int key = 0;
    unsigned long l = str.length();
    int power = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        key = (key + str[i] * power) % size;
        power *= alphabet;
        power %= size;
    }
    return key;
}
bool insert(string str)
{
    bool isSuccesful = false;
    unsigned int key = getHash(str);
    isSuccesful = (table[key].insert(str).second);
    return isSuccesful;
}
```

};

Насколько я понимаю, следует изменить функцию insert. Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом?

Comment: Ну вот как вам ответить?... Или нужно переделывать все - логика совершенно другая, здесь нужно, например, совершенно иное извлечение, рехеширование по заполнению etc... Или просто проигнорировать ваш вопрос :(

Comment: Я вот ничего не понял. Разве открытая адресация это не способ выбора корзин (значение хэша превращается в номер корзины - кольцо по модулю количества корзин), а метод цепочек - хранение элементов в списке в каждой корзине (чтобы для элементов с одинаковым хэшем в корзине была цепочка элементов) ???